# BitmapFactory.decodeResource returns null value

Tags: android

I am tring to load bitmaps from an internal resource in a View object (the source itself is in "drawable" files).

the code is:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;


public class BannerView extends View {



 private Bitmap m_Banner = null;

 public BannerView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
  super(context, attributeSet);

  m_Banner = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.banner);

 }
}
```

Why m_Banner value is null?

thank you in advance

Kobi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please make sure that all the sdk componenets (E.G Eclipse, Android SDK, SDK plug in for eclipse are all up to date).

Answer (score 4):

Eclipse Project -> Clean helped in my case.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem too, but I've found that if I put the picture into **drawable-ldpi**, it works fine. I do not know why, but this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I got null when i used a jpeg image file. But when i converted it to png and then used it in the same place it worked correctly

Answer (score 0):

my problem was that i was using R.drawable.clickCamera, but clickCamera was actually an XML drawable (for a button with selectable states), not an actual image. that was silly.

Answer (score -1):

Check options parameter when calling BitmapFactory.decodeResource. It is third parameter of this method and have to be set to false for returning a bitmap.