# BitmapFactory.decodeResource returns null even when using resource from context

Tags: android, android-view, android-drawable, android-bitmap

I have checked all other similar questions and no one helped me. Here is my code to get a `bitmap`:

```
public class HachureView extends View {

  //...

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

       //...
       bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(), R.drawable.hachure);
       bitmap.prepareToDraw();
       canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, mPaint);
    }
}
```

Here is hachure.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/hacure3"
    android:tileModeY="repeat" />
```

and hacure3 is a `png` file in `drawable` folder.

The problem is `decodeResource` always returns null.

According [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501863/android-bitmapfactory-decoderesource-returning-null) question using resource from `context.getResource()` solves the problem. But it didn't work for me.

Also I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4403632/bitmapfactory-decoderesource-returns-null-value) and cleaned the project and it didn't work again.

I just found a trick [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14553767/2779803). Although it works correctly, this is not the answer to my question that is why `decodeResource()` returns null:

```
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(resId);
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
```

**Note 1**: I have replaced `hacure3.png` with other `png` files and also some material design icons and nothing changed.

**Note 2:** When `hacure.xml` is open, the preview window in android studio shows the image correctly.

Comment: Your png file is too big. Size and resolution please?

Comment: `R.drawable.hachure` points to a `BitmapDrawable`, not to a `Bitmap`, so you can get it by calling `getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.hachure)`

Comment: @greenapps My png is 21*22 pixels, 249 bytes.

Comment: @pskink So you mean I must create drawable and get bitmap from it in order to create a bitmap? As I mentioned above?

Comment: what do you need a bitmap for?  cannot you use a drawable?

Comment: @pskink In my case, yes, I can use drawable. But generally I'll be glad to know the solution. Could you please post your comment as answer so I can accept it?

Comment: if you need a Bitmap use `R.drawable.hacure3` in `decodeResource`

Comment: @MisaghEmamverdi your **getBitmap()** method didn't work for me. Pls does anyone know why or how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

In place of using bitmap xml as resource, you can access the png as bitmap directly by passing png image as resource, eg:

```
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(), R.drawable.hacure3);
```

Comment: I created the bitmap xml file to set title mode as repeat. hacure3 dose not repeat itself.

Comment: @MisaghEmamverdi this is what differs `Bitmap` from `BitmapDrawable` which can repeat its content

Comment: @pskink In bitmap drawable I set this attribute: `android:tileModeY="repeat"`. I don't know bitmap repeats itself without any additional attribute or not. I just searched before how to repeat image and found that solution.

Comment: you can also use a BitmapShader

Answer (score 0):

I have had same issue. The reason was Android Studio - just assembled bad APK, with broken resources class. Clean/Rebuild may help.

Answer (score 0):

this solved my issue.

I tried to move image files (png,jpg) from **drawable-v24** to **drawable**